# How to securely transfer from an old private key, to a new one?

Tags: security, digital-signature, pki, key-management

I can sign the new (public) key with the old (private) key to securely transfer from one to the other. But far as I can tell, there's nothing stopping anyone who gets the old key from signing a different new key as official, even much later after I've given the old one up.

If I revoke the old private key, nobody can make that bogus signature, which is good. But doesn't revoking a key mean its signature of the new one would be invalidated? (As well as every single signature it's made?)

So someone who knows me as "Alice" would be able to tell I'm the same, even if I'm "Bob." But then they see "Alice"'s revocation, in which case they have to throw all of their knowledge about me away, whether Alice or Bob?

Comment: How did you establish your ownership for the original keypair? Can you repeat that process for the new one?

Comment: security.stackexchange.com would be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to deal with this is to use a different key for signing keys and for signing “useful” data.

The data signing key lives on an online server where it's invoked automatically, and thus is at risk of misuse. This key is rotated regularly. In principle, it wouldn't need to be rotated: just revoke it if something bad happens. But in practice revocation is hard: it's often difficult to ensure that every party that relies on the signatures will see the revocation message in a timely way. Expiration ensures that even if a party doesn't see the revocation message, it won't keep accepting compromised signatures for long.

The key signing key lives on an offline server with stringent access control, and since it's a lot better protected, it has a very low risk of being compromised.

A system with keys that sign other keys is called a [public key infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). Many systems have multiple levels of signing keys. The best known PKI ecosystem is the one used for HTTPS, with servers having a [certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) signed by an intermediate [certificate authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority), which in turn has a certificate signed by another CA until you reach a root CA. Intermediate CAs are online, but run specialized systems which do nothing but sign certificates. The keys to root CA certificates are split among multiple employees who all get together into a vault with no Internet connection once every few years to generate a new intermediate key.

Running your own CA with OpenSSL is not trivial, but it's doable, and you'll find many tutorials on the web.